# Can a WCF service hosted as windows service accessed from both windows and web clients?

Tags: angular, windows, wcf, iis

I currently have a WCF service hosted as a window service. I'm consuming this service from a windows console application through a TCP binding. Everything is fine with that. Now, I'm writing an Angular app which should also consume the same service. I was wondering if I can define a HTTP binding on the same service. I do not want to host the same service on IIS for the web client. Is there a way to continue to use the service hosted already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, angular app consumes web service which is Restful-style service, but WCF Service communicate with the client by using SOAP message, and the browser does not support SOAP message. In that case, we use the WebHttpBinding to create HTTP-mode web service, and then we could access it by the browser. we also could access it by javascript(ajax).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-basic-wcf-web-http-service

Comment: I'm assuming this service will be hosted in IIS? Is it not possible to consume the service hosted as windows service?

Comment: No problem, but we need to pay attention to cross domain problem.